# error:Connection reset (Gradle sync failed: Connection reset)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am importing constraint-layout-start to android studio 3.0. I have kept in androidstudioproject folder that's the the path where all my android studio projects are stored. after importing its showing **connection reset error**. Here is the log file link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W1mGmIc67baZb4C5nGGecWm15ggB0Wp5/view?usp=sharing

i have all the SDK installed. tried to manually change the sdk verion to 21 which was running perfectly for my other projects, but here it didn't work.

i checked all the files are okay, i am not getting why this error occurs.
images of gradle page are given below.

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rABv4.png)

[gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUn13.png)

Comment: Can I suggest that you paste the relevant snippet of the log in your question so that the question is complete without having to click unknown links.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i will surely update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add google repository to your gradle file:

```
repositories {
    maven()
    //other repositories...
    google()
}
```

Try to download from SDK manager:
[SDK Manager Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr7zv.png)

Check your gradle and plugin version:
https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle

Comment: // sorry, it didn't work,i tried your suggestion also.

Comment: Are you using VPN or proxy?

Comment: Try to install from SDK Manager, I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating, link was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For Android studio 3.0.0

required Gradle version: 4.1

File > Project Structure > Project

required Build Tools 26.0.2

Comment: Thanks all for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

**For Android Studio 3.4 Canary 8**

Hope it will helpful!
            Go To File>Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment>Gradle

and set your Android studio local gradle path like below image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i solve this problem in this way. be careful it causes with different problems like using proxy, dns connection windows , fire wall block , ....

anyway, i use proxy in file/settings/proxy in android studio and after that i set no proxy. after that whenever use kerio vpn or cisco gradle  didnt work.

solution :open gradle.properties  and remove every proxy script from there and sync gradle and work fine

**For Testing** if you are under **a firewall block**,visit this site : https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip or whatever version is in your gradle-wrapper.properties file. If the page does not open / downloads, then confirmed, you are under a firewall block. Visit https://gradle.org/releases/ to get the url. If you are in a home setup, you might need to change modem settings / contact ISP, but if you are in your office setup, check with your IT Support Team.